# Thumbnail CSS forces div to next line

Tags: javascript, html, css-float

I have three DIVs on a page, each holding some text.  Each DIV is of class HomeBlock:

```
    .HomeBlock
     {
        border:  1px solid;
        float:   left;
        padding: 8px;
        margin:  5px 0px 5px 4px;
        width:   310px;
        height:  350px;
     }
```

All is right with the world until I put my thumbnail routine in the first DIV.  The thumbnail routine allows the user to have the mouse over the thumbnail and pop up the associated image full size.  Check out www.casnChoir.com for an example that works.

In this application it pushes the 3rd DIV to the next line.  Can anyone spot why?

Here is the thumbnail html:

```
       <div style="float:left">
       <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"> 
       <img style="width: 100px; padding: 4px 4px 5px 5px;" 
                   src="../css/images/ktmscreen.jpg" 
                   border="0" alt="" /> 
       <span><img src="../css/images/ktmscreen.jpg" alt="" /> </span></a></div>
```

The image ktmscreen.jpg is 700px x 522px.

Here is the CSS for the thumbnail:

```
        .thumbnail{
         position: relative;
         z-index: 0;
          }

        .thumbnail:hover{
         background-color: transparent;
         z-index: 50;
          }

        .thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
         position:         absolute;
         background-color: lightyellow;
         padding:          5px;
         top:              -350px;
         left:             160px;
         border:           2px solid;
         visibility:       hidden;
         color:            black;
         text-decoration:  none;
          }

        .thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
         border-width:     2px;
         padding:          2px;
          }    

        .thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
         visibility:       visible;
         top:              -350px;
         left:             160px; /*position where enlarged image
                                   should offset horizontally */

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

change your CSS like this:

```
    .thumbnail span {
     /*CSS for enlarged image*/
     position: absolute;
     background-color: lightyellow;
     padding: 5px;
     top: -350px;
     left: 160px;
     border: 2px solid;
     display:none;
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 .thumbnail span img {
     /*CSS for enlarged image*/
     border-width: 2px;
     padding: 2px;
 }
 .thumbnail:hover span {
     /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
     display:block
     /* or try inline */
     top: -350px;
     left: 160px;
     /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
 }
```

keep in mind that visibility only toggles the visibility of the element, but the element itself still exists and has all the properties (width, height, etc), hence it will push any element if it needs space. On the opposite, `display:none` "takes the element out of the layout", as if it didn't exist. Alternatively, you can keep using visibility keeping on mind to adjust the height and width as needed. Keep in mind you're showing like 1/4 of the needed code, so there might be some adjustment needed, but quite probably this will be enough for you to isolate the issue and fix it